# Keep original image data when saving to pdf

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, pdf

I have plots that I annotate using images:

```
def add_image(axe, filename, position, zoom):
    img = plt.imread(filename)
    off_img = matplotlib.offsetbox.OffsetImage(img, zoom = zoom, resample = False)
    art = matplotlib.offsetbox.AnnotationBbox(off_img, position, xybox = (0, 0),
        xycoords = axe.transAxes, boxcoords = "offset points", frameon = False)
    axe.add_artist(art)
```

Then I save the figure to some pdf file, say `fig.pdf`. I expect the exact original image to be embedded in the resulting pdf, without resampling. However, the image is resampled according to the `dpi` parameter of `savefig()`.

**How can I force matplotlib to *NOT* resample the image (there is no point in doing that for a vector output anyway) ?**

For more details, here is a simple example, using [this image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png) as `image.png`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("agg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def add_image(axe, filename, position, zoom):
    img = plt.imread(filename)
    off_img = matplotlib.offsetbox.OffsetImage(img, zoom = zoom, resample = False)
    art = matplotlib.offsetbox.AnnotationBbox(off_img, position, xybox = (0, 0),
        xycoords = axe.transAxes, boxcoords = "offset points", frameon = False)
    axe.add_artist(art)

# ==========
fig = plt.figure()
axe = plt.axes()
fig.set_size_inches(3, 1.5)
axe.plot(np.arange(10), np.arange(10))

add_image(axe, "image.png", position = (0.2, 0.7), zoom = 0.07)

fig.savefig("temp.pdf", bbox_inches = "tight", pad_inches = 0)
```

## Expected result:

[image: expected]

## Actual result:

[image: actual]

**EDIT:** [There is a bug/feature issue for this question](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/16268)

Comment: Matplotlib should not resample the image unless being asked to do so. Can you show a [mcve] where it does?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yes, I know MWEs, I just thought the code given was sufficient. Anyway, I posted a full minimal example, please note that I explicitely added `resample = False` but it doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: Oh, you put in a big picture and create a really tiny one. So at some point you have to have it resampled. In this case, just use a much larger dpi, e.g. `dpi=1000` should do.

Comment: `resample = False` is the default for [`OffsetImage`](https://matplotlib.org/api/offsetbox_api.html#matplotlib.offsetbox.OffsetImage) so setting it explicitly shouldn't make any difference... in any case the resampling is happening downstream from `OffsetImage`

Comment: Images in PDF definitely have a dpi.  https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat/check-dpi-pdf/td-p/9838172

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Is there really no way to just pass the image through ? As in @JodyKlymak links, each bitmap is its own entity with its own dpi, so I would expect matplotlib to just copy the data without attempting to adjust the dpi...

Comment: I dug into matplotlib code, and the resample is hard-coded to follow a unique dpi (`matplotlib/image.py`, function `_ImageBase._make_image()` and related). Is this right, or should I request a feature ?

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick summary of the discussion in https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/16268:

- Passing the image through without resampling is indeed a desireable feature, mostly because for vector output, it should really be up to the renderer (e.g. pdf viewer, printer etc.) to determine the resolution.
- The fact that matplotlib currently does not allow for this is mostly an oversight.
- A workaround solution (a quick hack) is to add the following code before producing the figure:

  ```
  from matplotlib.backends.backend_mixed import MixedModeRenderer

  def _check_unsampled_image(self, renderer):
      if isinstance(renderer, MixedModeRenderer):
          return True
      else:
          return False

  matplotlib.image.BboxImage._check_unsampled_image = _check_unsampled_image
  ```

  This is not meant to be used in production code though, and a more robust solution needs to be implemented in a future matplotlib version. Contributions are welcome.

Comment: I deleted my answer, figured it's better to preempt the possible confusion it would cause future readers. Wanted to ping you in case you want to edit your answer to reflect my deletion since my answer is referenced.